# How can I write an asynchronous type assertion function?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, types, syntax, type-assertion

Since TypeScript 3.7, one can write a type assertion function like so:

```
function assertsIsArray(x: any): asserts x extends Array<any> {
  if(!Array.isArray(x)) throw new Error();
}
```

However the `asserts` clause takes the place of the return type statement in the function declaration. Normally one does not need to return from these functions, but this makes declaring `async` functions apparently impossible:

```
async function assertsIsArray(x: any): asserts x extends Array<any> {
  if(!Array.isArray(x)) throw new Error();
}

// Type 'void' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
```

Often, validation needs to be asynchronous (ie with [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup)). How can I make an async type assertion method?

Comment: heh wow, I don't think this is possible.  looking at [microsoft/TypeScript#34636](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34636) and other issues

Comment: You can use conventional promise chaining for that purpose: [PG](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8-Beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgMDMCuA7AYxgEsI84BDAZyuFioEkqBBKKCgTwAoQAuSvBwCU-arXpwQcYlTit2HADwVBAPkQY40rHC4BCeZwB0Mw9xBChcGAAsoEAO5w8wJwFE20LkIDcGNJjoACbABAA2FFDAcLiEJGQxwDAENgDKEAC2STbEeADm3vwACvYZMsDKanAA9NXWObIycBwQOFCJyTZyRQwY2PhEpOR5SQDyUAAqdo5mPKKCIgIcANoAuhroWmJ0MIwsbJw8QppwUTBt5CD+fegEZFTwke0AvJQOFMTwWEkp6Vm2uQKQiMtmAeC4Ixg4ym9gcZmO6FqcCCEDgVEy2UBcAcny6T3mK1WQA)

Comment: Three years on, this is still not possible: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681